# Counting growth rings in fish bone images

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision, signal-processing, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to count the number of growth rings in images of fish bones, which look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WLLm.png) (I'm only interested in the final count, which is 4 in this case).

The task is somewhat similar to counting growth rings in trees, but as you can see for yourself, the number of rings can sometimes be very hard to see here, and it generally requires expert knowledge to count them. Also, the number seems to vary in different directions from the center of the bone (the brightest part).

I have tried different image analysis techniques, and used mostly OpenCV, but I'm able to get only the approximate count.

I am interested if anyone has an idea, based on their experience, how would a (end-to-end or not, convolutional or not) neural network behave on a dataset like this, provided that I have enough data for such a NN. Would a NN be able to capture features and patterns which are hard to detect for us and do the task? Each image is annotated only with its count.

Also, I'm open to any kind of different suggestions and approaches on this task.

Comment: This sounds like it would require a significant amount of R&D work to develop a custom algorithm for doing this. If it is possible with current techniques at all.

Comment: I agree, this is far from trivial. Looks like an interesting PhD thesis project.

Comment: To me, this looks like a challenge, but possibly not as difficult as the above 2 comments imply. I don't think the NN approach will work well (though not my expertise). Instead, I'd figure out what the algorithms are that people use to mark those ring (ie, there are lots of partial rings, why did they pick those?, is the center always a white blob?, etc), and try to create an algo that mimics that. For example, look for concentric bands that form a partial arc (eg, you could just try just summing up the pixels along sets of concentric ellipses that contain the white blob, etc).

Comment: Better data might help too. It will be difficult to get rid of the spurious bright and dark spots based on reflections of the light source.  Could the samples be back-lit?